# How can I run Spring with MongoDB disabled, but still installed?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I was reading through this Git issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7589
with regards to Java Spring boot and am trying to figure out a way to bypass the crash upon startup.

The short version is that If you include the code for creating the mongo client:

```
@Bean
public MongoOperations mongoOperations() {
    try {
        //This runs an operation which uses my credentials to login to the db
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the MongoDB is running, it will connect and not have any problems, but if the MongoDB is *not* running, Spring will retry and after failing again, will crash and stop all startup sequences.

**My question is this: is there a way to bypass this initial crash / check against the DB being up and running other than commenting out all code referencing it? Can I catch an exception somewhere low-level and let it pass through?**

Comment: If application uses database right from startup (or during startup for initial data loading) how could it ignore the fact that database is down? You could try to lazily initialize Spring beans: in this case if mongoDb is not used at runtime code above will not be called at all.

Comment: can you share what is your approach on that finally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application behaves in such a way that MongoDB is optional, you have several options.

If you are migrating an existing application, the easiest from a start would be to [exclude the auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration) and create the infrastructure yourself. Not in the way you've indicated as returning `null` from a `@Bean` method is quite nasty. Rather you could have some service that could lazily create the client and you could update your optional usages of MongoDB to go through that service. The service would be created regardless but would only create the underlying infrastructure if necessary.

The other option is to use a profile. If the main use case is that MongoDB is available then create a `application-nomongo.properties` (something like that) where you would exclude the auto-configuration using the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property. When the application starts without mongo, you can enable the `nomongo` profile and the auto-configuration will backoff. When it's not enabled, the `Mongo` bean will be created by Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I want my application to be able to run offline as well, queue stuff and from time to time flush to database. This means it needs to be able to launch offline and connect whenever internet is available. Ofc, Spring crashed my app when it did not succeed in connecting.
What worked for me was this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(bootstrapMode = BootstrapMode.LAZY)
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("xxx");
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("xxx");
    hikariConfig.setUsername("xxx");
    hikariConfig.setPassword("xxx");

    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");
    hikariConfig.setInitializationFailTimeout(-1);

    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager() {
    return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("blabla");
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return em;
}

private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect");

    return properties;
}
}
```

Also, place this in your App class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

application.yml looks like this:

```
#Spring properties
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: "xxx"
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    continue-on-error: true
  hikari:
    connection-timeout: 2000
    initialization-fail-timeout: -1
    auto-commit: true
```

This works for me, hopefully it will work for you guys as well, I saw many posts around here searching for a solution to this. Good luck!