# spring boot entityManagerFactory initialization after login

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx

I develop a JavaFX application with spring boot. This application uses local database (H2), however the database connection properties like database name, username, password are entered by the user at the login screen.

But spring boot initializes all beans defined in AppConfig.java, and i'm not able to initialize javafx scene to show the UI.

Putting exclude to @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation doesn't help.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})   
public class MyApplication extends Application {
```

spring boot still tries to connect to the database.

Of course once the user enters db name, username/password, spring boot should initialize database related beans or somehow to force spring boot for the initialization, because later on they're required for the application functionality.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: I edited my answer with some code examples. Please, let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start the login screen before spring boot and then set the entered values as system properties. And after that start Spring Boot:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Start login screen

    // For all properties the user entered
    System.setProperty("spring.database.xy", "<value from UI>");

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Comment: To be honest i thought there is some different solution.This might work indeed. I need to redesign my application, to have the login screen a modal dialog, and after a login show the main view with menu system, and other components.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You may provide your own DataSource bean using a wrapper which initialize datasource only when connection is needed.</s>

Your DataSource wrapper may provide `setUsername()` and `setPassword()` you can use on your login attempt.

I didn't tried this out, but let me know if there's something wrong.

```java
public class AppDataSourceWrapper implements DataSource {

    private final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public AppDataSourceWrapper(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        this.dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource() {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            initDataSource();
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    private void initDataSource() {
        this.dataSource = dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return getDataSource().getConnection();
    }

    // other override methods omitted for brevity

}
```

Add to your config:

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    return new AppDataSourceWrapper(dataSourceProperties);
}
```

On user access request you can do something like:

```java
AppDataSourceWrapper dsWrapper = (AppDataSourceWrapper) dataSource;
dsWrapper.setUsername(username);
dsWrapper.setPassword(password);
```

Then DataSource should be initialized on your first connection attempt.

#### UPDATE

Spring Boot JPA autoconfiguration tries to connect to the database during beans initialization (i.e. `JpaVendorAdapter` bean in `JpaBaseConfiguration`), thus providing a data source wrapper won't do the job.

Possible solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952078/3666539).

Comment: that's fine, but how this resolves my issue? as long as i put dataSource() method in AppConfig.java, spring-boot loads this bean as well

Comment: @pillesoft Bean is loaded and can be injected, but it shouldn't throws exceptions if you don't perform any connection before setting username and password in your (I suppose) LoginController. Otherwise edit your question with stacktrace or other usefull code. I couldn't test my code before posting it, so there could be errors or I may have made wrong assumptions.

Comment: i have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in pom.xml as dependency. due to that spring tries to setup database connection automatically for me. I want to skip that auto configuration/setup at the application startup, and initiate it at LoginController, when I have the database connection parameters.

Comment: Ok, after some tries, I can tell you that Spring tests connection during initialization (called by `JpaVendorAdapter` bean annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`) and there's no _easy_ way to disable it. Take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952078/3666539) for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a sort of dynamic/lazy datasource bean.
You could try to accomplish this by creating a custom RoutingDatasource implementation extending *org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource*.

You could search on SessionRoutingDataSource, DynamicRoutingDatasource or MultitenantDatasource if you want some examples.

You could try working with some sort of NoopDatasource in your RoutingDatasource for scenario's where you need a datasource to be there but the user has not yet provided the creds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding spring boot starter JPA and datasource properties for initialization.

Keep the properties for datasource but name it to something that spring boot doesn't look for.Then I would initialize datasource at login by creating DataSource object.

Another option would be to define a dataSource bean and mark it lazy.