# Lazy Database initialization with Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I want to prevent database initialization, including Hikari DataSource pool initialization, until the first query attempt has been made. So far I have tried

- setting `spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=0` and `spring.datasource.hikari.initializationFailTimeout=-1` in the `application.properties`
- Setting `@Lazy` to Entity and Repository

But it is not working. Is anyone able to successfully achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695889/how-to-lazy-initialize-spring-boot-datasourcespring-data

Comment: Tried the solutions to the above questions but it does not have any effect.

Comment: What is your springboot version ?

Comment: Database Initialization happen when the service starts, are you trying to delay this untill the first query attempt is made? so basically you want to initiate the DB connection when you are trying to call the first query?

Comment: @anand - Yes, We want to delay it until the first query happens and also process should not fail if DB is not available.

Comment: @AmolGharpure - We're on version 2.4