# Lazy load spring auto configuration

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I have dependency in my spring boot project which fetches values of some properties using Spring's EnvironmentPostProcessor.
Now these properties are database credentials and not everyone has access to the credential since there is no dev environment for the db in question. I just want to change the configuration that the credentials don't get fetched on dev or local environment on application startup as that would result in a error and the application will fail to start.

```
Class A implements EnvironmentPostProcessor{}
```

I tried to use @Lazy annotation on the Class Annoteted with @ConfigurationProperties. I also tried using my own BeanFactoryPostProcessor (with @Order(HighestPrecedence) to programmatically set the A to lazy load, but it gets called before my BeanFactoryPostProcessor's postProcessBeanFactory method.
Is what I'm trying to achieve possible and am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Do you mind posting the error message you are getting - There are a couple of ways you can solve this and the error message would help :)

Comment: @Reg I can't post the exact stack trace of the exception but exception comes in an EnvironmentPostProcessor's(EPP) postProcessEvent ... in the postProcessEvent the app is trying to fetch a credential that the user is not entitled to see hence the exception is thrown. I'm just trying to make it some how that this EPP is not loaded at startup for certain environments .... namely local environment...

Answer (score 1):

`@Lazy` is only to be used with `@Bean` or `@Component` (Or any `@Component`-based annotations ex. `@Service`)

*Take note*: You can also add it to a `@Configuration` class, but that just means that all Beans in the class are annotated with `@Lazy`

`@Lazy` is a bit of a weird annotation in general; it should be seen as an IF possible then lazy load. If some other bean needs the lazy bean, the lazy bean will be initialized. (*It's like the Pirate code, more of a guideline than an enforced rule*)

Finally, marking `@ConfigurationProperties` with @Lazy seems a bit odd. As Spring will need these Configuration property "beans" to create the Spring Context.

*However*, the common use case for `@Lazy` is a failing database connection, preventing the application from starting. See the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695889/how-to-lazy-initialize-spring-boot-datasourcespring-data) if that is what you are running into.
**Summary:**
You can configure your repositories to be lazy-loaded with:

`spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy`

**Last remark (Me just guessing)**

If you wish to change properties once your application is already running, I would look at the following [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties). It goes into manually reloading configuration and also [@RefreshScope](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/refresh/RefreshScope.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html) `EnvironmentPostProcessor`s must be registered via `META-INF/spring.factories`:

> Allows for customization of the application's Environment prior to the
> application context being refreshed. EnvironmentPostProcessor
> implementations have to be registered in META-INF/spring.factories,
> using the fully qualified name of this class as the key.
> Implementations may implement the Ordered interface or use an @Order
> annotation if they wish to be invoked in specific order.